# JPEG encoder - set quality from command line

Tags: java, jpeg, encoder

I'm building a JPEG image encoder. As it stands, in order to encode an image the user enters the name of the file they wish to encode and name of the file to be created as a result.

I'd like the user to be able to set the quality of the encoding in the command line. I tried renaming the second argument (100) in `new JpegEncoder(image, 100, new FileOutputStream(args[1]));
     encoder.Compress();` to `args[2]` but that didn't work.

```
public class JPGencoder {

  public static void main ( String[] args ) {
  String[] names = ImageIO.getWriterFormatNames();
  BufferedImage image = null;
  JpegEncoder encoder = null; 

  try {
     image = ImageIO.read( new File( args[0] ) );
      System.err.println("Process image " + args[0]);
      System.err.println(image.toString());
  } catch (Exception e) { 
      System.err.println("Problems with image " + args[0]);
  }

  try {
     encoder = new JpegEncoder(image, 100, new FileOutputStream(args[1]));
     encoder.Compress();
  } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("well that didn't work");
  }
```

}
}

Comment: How do you mean did not work? Note `100` is an `int` and `args[2]` is a `String`.

Comment: How do I set it to take in an int then?

Comment: That doesn't work; I get an exception from the second try catch block.

Comment: Can you print the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this definition of [JpegEncoder](http://www.koders.com/java/fid646C951F5C8FC602AFB2336581C6415368DE590A.aspx) the second argument to the `JpegEncode` constructor is an `int`.

The type of `args[2]` is a `String` so presumably by "*did not work*" you mean "*did not compile*". To convert `args[2]` to an `int`:

```
Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
```

This will throw a `NumberFormatException` if `args[2]` is not a valid `int`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not difficult to set the JPG compression/quality using `ImageIO`.  Here are some snippets that might get you started.

```
private ImageWriteParam imageWriterParams;
private ImageWriter imageWriter;
File out = new File("some.jpg");
// ...

Iterator it = ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("jpg");
// presume every iterator has precisely 1 writer
imageWriter = (ImageWriter)it.next();
imageWriterParams = imageWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
if ( imageWriterParams.canWriteCompressed() ) {
    try {
        imageWriterParams.setCompressionMode( ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT );
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, "ImageWriter cannot compress!");
}
imageWriterParams.setCompressionQuality(qualF);

FileImageOutputStream fios = new FileImageOutputStream(out);
imageWriter.setOutput(fios);
imageWriter.write(
    null,
    new IIOImage(image,null,null),
    imageWriterParams );
fios.flush();
fios.close();
```

Comment: @mKorbel  Got a -1 on that post & another post in the same minute.  Guess I must have p1ssed someone off (again).  ;)

Comment: another SO's tags are very funny, sometimes I look into VB/VBA/VBE or Windows OS rellated answers, brrrrr I run away, sweet home :-)